# Python 3.x ImportError: No module named configparser , but module is installed

Tags: python, windows, configparser, python-3.7

In my code i am using configparser. Everything working fine, but after i do fresh install of windows 10, this error appears: `ImportError: No module named configparser`.

- But same code working on other pc
- Python is in PATH (double checked)
- Try reinstall python
- configparser is installed by default, but still try "pip install configparser"

I am using Python 3.7.1
In same code i do "`import os`" and this is working. Configparser is in same directory.

**EDIT:**

configparser is here:

```
c:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\configparser.py
```

after `pip install configparser`, there is another:

```
c:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\backports\configparser\__init__.py
```

**EDIT_2:**

Try copy:

```
c:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\configparser.py
```

to my working folder. Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\git\silixcon_lib\production_data.py", line 4, in <module>
import configparser
File "C:\git\silixcon_lib\configparser.py", line 434
option, section, rawval, var) from None
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**This is working:**

Copy this to my working folder:

```
c:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\backports\configparser\__init__.py
```

and rename it to configparser.py. At lines 138-140 change "backports.configparser.helpers" to "helpers"

and this copy too:

```
c:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\backports\configparser\helpers.py
```

Comment: Could you share the code snippet of what is going wrong.

Comment: May I see the output of `pip show configparser`

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python  `  

`import configparser  `
`import os  `
`import fnmatch  `


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\git\silixcon_lib\production_data.py", line 4, in <module>
    import configparser
ImportError: No module named configparser

Comment: `pip show configparser`
Have no output...

Comment: If you have more then one version of python installed on your machine or you have the same version but one is system one and the other you installed manually, maybe you're using `pip` for the wrong one. Try using some virtual environment

Comment: You seem to have found a solution to your problem. Please write that as an answer not as an edit to your question. It's fine to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Found cause**

During instalation Platformio-ide to Atom editor, python 2.7 was installed. Python 3.7 was in path and when i run:

```
python -V
```

I see my python 3.7 version. Bud when i run python script it starts in python 2.7.

But this:

```
python my_script.py
```

starts python 3.7.

So problem is in association .py file extension. But for unknown reason a can not change .py to run in python 3.7. So for now i uninstall platformio and everything starts working.